# Respond 6 Install Error with angular2-jwt.js

Tags: angular, gulp, respondcms

I am trying to follow the installation instructions for install Respond CMS from Github.

I'm getting stuck on copying files to the public folder using gulp.

*https://respondcms.com/documentation/installation-from-github and it's the third command on step 2.*

This is the error in short that I'm getting after typing `gulp` into my terminal. I'm currently calling this command from the diamond/app folder. **(diamond is my alias for respond)**

```
Error: File not found with singular glob: /home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
```

In an effort to provide more details below I have provided all terminal data from the point I entered the command to where I stopped.

```
userMasked@domainMasked [~/public_html/diamond/app]# gulp
[17:56:08] Using gulpfile ~/public_html/diamond/app/gulpfile.js
[17:56:08] Starting 'default'...
[17:56:08] Starting 'copy-libs'...
[17:56:12] Finished 'copy-libs' after 3.9 s
[17:56:12] Starting 'copy-folders'...
[17:56:12] Finished 'copy-folders' after 17 ms
[17:56:12] Starting 'copy-files'...
[17:56:12] 'copy-files' errored after 2.33 ms
[17:56:12] Error: File not found with singular glob: /home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:41:11)
    at Glob.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Glob._finish (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:172:8)
    at done (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:159:12)
    at Glob._processSimple2 (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:652:12)
    at /home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:640:10
    at Glob._stat2 (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:736:12)
    at lstatcb_ (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:728:12)
    at RES (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:23:14)
    at f (/home/userMasked/public_html/diamond/app/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
[17:56:12] 'default' errored after 3.93 s
userMasked@domainMasked [~/public_html/diamond/app]#
```

**UPDATE**

Upon further inspection, it appears `angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js` isn't even loaded inside the `node_modules` folder. So my question is, does Respond CMS need that module or is it something I can ignore and just change the `gulpfile.js` file to not include it?

If it is something that is still needed, how would I go about getting it added to the node_modules folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue too, I'm not absolute on why it's missing from the respondcms installation but you can just install the module and move on.

From the respondcms app/ directory:

```
npm install angular2-jwt
```

Gulp should work fine then. Good luck.